# Как из списка узнать сколько раз повторяется элемент и вывести количество повторения в переменную (python)

Tags: python, list, список

Как узнать сколько раз повторялся элемент в списке и вывести это количество в переменную.

Вот код:

```
n = int(input())
x = []

for i in range(n):
    x.append(input())
    
z = []

for i in x:
    z.append(i)
    print(z)
```

Ввод:

```
5
A
ABA
ABA
A
A
```

Comment: `list.count(value)`.

Comment: Используйте `collections.Counter`. Или это задание и надо без использования библиотек?

Comment: @CrazyElf да без библиотек

Comment: @SamSamovich Тогда делайте словарь, ключ - элемент списка, значение - счётчик повторений, это наиболее "низкоуровневый" вариант. Если ключа нет в словаре - добавляете со значением 0. Потом добавляете 1 к значению по ключу. И так для каждого элемента списка. Потом печатаете получившийся словарь.

Comment: спасибо, я попытаюсь!